# UITextView set NSTextAttachment Images cause Performance lag, slow issue

Tags: ios, swift, performance, text, uitextview

I want to add Images attachment to UITextview whenever user typing, That's work well but the problem is CPU grow as much as number of images attachment added. 90%. And cause UI lag and so slow. I have resized images to small size but problem still happened. [here is image what I'm doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peUeN.png)

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
     
        
        for data in arrDataModel {
                  if data.textDefaul == text {
                      let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                      if let image = data.imageData {

                          let imageNew = UIImage(data: image)!
                          attachment.image = imageNew
                         let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
                         txtViewShow.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: attString)
                      
                      }

                   break

                  }
          }
        
         return true
         
                
      }
```

Comment: its seem uitextview redraw all of attachments whenever add new. but I don't know how to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are holding `imageData: Data` **in memory** for all your model instances. You should avoid doing this. You can create the `UIImage` instance from a `String (resourceName)` any time you want.

For example, here's what I have in my `Assets.xcassets`.
[image]

###### Note : The additional white space will be useful in the implementation.

Then you could do it like following -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    let alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", 
                     "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    struct AlphabetInfo {
        let alphabet: String
        
        var image: UIImage? {
            UIImage(named: "alphabet_\(alphabet)")
        }
    }

    lazy var alphabetInfos: [AlphabetInfo] = {
        alphabets.map { AlphabetInfo(alphabet: $0) }
    }()

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        for info in alphabetInfos {
            if info.alphabet == text.uppercased() {
                if let image = info.image {
                    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                    attachment.image = image
                    attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
                    let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
                    textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: attachmentString)
                }
                break
            }
        }
        
        var cursorLocation = textView.selectedRange.location
        if text.isEmpty {
            textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: text)
            cursorLocation -= range.length
        } else {
            cursorLocation += text.count
        }
        textView.selectedRange.location = cursorLocation

        return false
    }
}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks you! but some reason I have to hold on but memory is not growing too much, it's normal, just CPU growing to 90% if I added 200+ attachment images.

Comment: I tried above example with ~200 images, didn't see any spike like that in the CPU. It was maximum 30% or so. I used `60x60` images - maybe your images are still too big. My resources' sizes are between `6KB and 8KB`.

Comment: the images are 50*50, really it much more 200+, it's growing 10%-30%-..90% if i typing continue

Comment: it's grow up to ~90% when added 570+ images

Comment: I see. I tried it with 1500+ attachments and I started the see the issue. See https://imgur.com/lROzlbi It is clearly because of `UITextView` having too many attachments to work with. You should consider solving this using a `UICollectionView` instead. Each character image will be inside a `UICollectionViewCell`. Your `UICollectionView` will have two sections - 1st one will use `AlphabetInfoCollectionViewCell` that will show alphabet info/image and 2nd section will use a different cell say `AlphabetTextInputCollectionViewCell` that will have a textField that will allow text entry.

Comment: As soon as you detect a character is entered in the second section `AlphabetTextInputCollectionViewCell`, you add the `AlphabetInfo` to the end of your data models array and reload 1st section only. 2nd section will continue to show keyboard entry part. And you will also have to use a simple `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass for this `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Dear! can you help me a small example. It's seem very hard to do for me!

Comment: You have to try it yourself. There are a ton of examples available to work with a `UICollectionView`.